# Bundle.getBoolean Null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, boolean

I have this piece of code:

```
  override var shouldShowUpload: Boolean
    get() = arguments.getBoolean(IS_LANDING_UPLOAD_PAGE, false)
    set(value) {
        value.let { arguments?.putBoolean(IS_LANDING_UPLOAD_PAGE, it) }
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
```

I don't want `shouldShowUpload` a nullable boolean. But what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Depends on what you wana return when arguments is null

Comment: @Selvin A false boolean

Comment: Then what stopping you from doing a null check and if it's true then return false and in other case return same value as you are returning now

Comment: Could you not do `arguments?.getBoolean(IS_LANDING_UPLOAD_PAGE, false) ?: false`

Comment: Thanks! It works @DavidRawson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `arguments` Bundle can be null. Check it for null and return what you need.

```
get() = arguments?.getBoolean(IS_LANDING_UPLOAD_PAGE, false) ?: false
```